# how do i map an array in react js i have tried but there is some problem can anyone help me

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I try to get data from localDataStorage and try to populate on screen in react but the react is showing error `[{',' expected" in place of '.' in jsx line localStorageData.iength or if i remove this from code than it's showing same error for 'localDataStorage.map' it asking me to remove '.'

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./inbox.css";
 
const Inbox = () => {
  const [localStorageData, setlocalStorageData] = useState([])

  useEffect =(()=>{
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')).then(data=> setlocalStorageData(data))
  }, [localStorageData])

  return (
    {localStorageData.length > 0 &&
       localDataStorage.map((element, index) => (
        <div className="inbox" key ={index}>
          <div className="bullet">&#x27A3;</div>
          <div className="msg">{element.message}</div>
          <div className="btn-container">
            <div className="date">{element.title}</div>
            <div className="edit btn hide">
              <i className="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i>
            </div>
            <div className="delete btn hide">
              <i className="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))
    }
  )
}

export default Inbox;
```

the error is as following

> ```
> [{
>   "resource": "/C:/Users/PC/Desktop/web/new/src/component/inbox/inbox.js",
>   "owner": "typescript",
>   "code": "1005",
>   "severity": 8,
>   "message": "',' expected.",
>   "source": "ts",
>   "startLineNumber": 14,
>   "startColumn": 22,
>   "endLineNumber": 14,
>   "endColumn": 23
> }]
> ```

Comment: correct the spelling of length at {localStorageData.iength > 0}

Comment: that happened while posting its ok in code

Comment: use ? operator like localStorageData?.length at map also. If localStorageData is undefined for first time, it will not throw error

Comment: wrap the return statement code in <></>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the outer braces in your return statement. Braces like this are only used inside JSX.

Also, you probably meant `.length` instead of `.iength`.

Comment: yes thanks u r right it resolve the issue thanks by removing braces and putting inside react fragment

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import "./inbox.css"

const Inbox = () => {
  const [localStorageData, setlocalStorageData] = useState([])

  useEffect =
    (() => {
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"))
        .then(data => setlocalStorageData(data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    },
    [localStorageData])

  return (
    <>
      {localStorageData.length > 0 &&
        localStorageData.map((element, index) => (
          <div className="inbox" key={index}>
            <div className="bullet">&#x27A3;</div>
            <div className="msg">{element.message}</div>
            <div className="btn-container">
              <div className="date">{element.title}</div>
              <div className="edit btn hide">
                <i className="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i>
              </div>
              <div className="delete btn hide">
                <i className="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
    </>
  )
}

export default Inbox
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not wrapping code into single element
try

```
return (
    <>
    {
      localStorageData.length > 0 &&
        localData.map((element, index) => (
          <div className="inbox" key={index}>
            <div className="bullet">&#x27A3;</div>
            <div className="msg">{element.message}</div>
            <div className="btn-container">
              <div className="date">{element.title}</div>
              <div className="edit btn hide">
                <i className="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i>
              </div>
              <div className="delete btn hide">
                <i className="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))
    }
    </>
  )
```

Answer (score -1):

i believe there should be localStorageData.map and not localData.map

Comment: check now it happened while posting those are not the reason for error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).